# Android: MyLocationOverlay.java -> Understanding issue

Tags: android, android-mapview, mylocationoverlay

The mentioned class has got the following method:

```
   protected void drawCompass(Canvas canvas, float bearing) {
    int offset = Math.max(canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth()) / 8;
    Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, 2*offset, 2*offset);
    canvas.drawBitmap(compassBase, null, r, paint);
    canvas.rotate(-bearing, offset, offset);
    canvas.drawBitmap(compassArrow, null, r, paint);
}
```

Link to the complete src: [MyLocationOverlay](http://gitorious.org/android-maps-api/android-maps-api/blobs/42614538ffda1a6985c398933a85fcd9afc752ee/src/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.java)

There they create a Rect r witch specifies where the both Bitmaps should be drawn on the canvas.

The java doc of drawBitmap says :"Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill the destination rectangle. If the source rectangle is not null, it specifies the subset of the bitmap to draw. "

Because both Bitmaps use the same Rect r and because they both are automatically scaled to fit the Rect, why is the result a perfect Compass when I activate the compass in the MapView.

To my mind the result should be crap, because the arrow of the compass is also scaled to fit the Rect.

So where is the error in reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

They are scaled using the same proportion, not to absolute size.  To answer your question, the canvas is drawn on using the bitmap as reference - think of it like a painter and a canvas painting one image on top of the other using two photo images as reference.